# How to properly use a target of an importing build file?

Tags: java, xml, ant

I am pretty new to `ant` and extended an existing build file `a.xml`:

I created an additional build file `b.xml` which is imported by `a.xml`. The target `example` defined in `b.xml` provides a new *(optional)* feature when building with ant, that requires the `${version}` property. The `${version}` property is *created/provided* by the target `determine.version` in `a.xml`.

To ensure the existence/access of `${version}` in `b.xml` I've added the `depends="determine.version"` parameter to the target `example` in `b.xml`. Thereby, I've added an dependency to a non-resolvable target, when running `b.xml` solely *(which is not intended)*.

#### The question:

I don't feel comfortable with this solution and want to ask whether there is a cleaner way to ensure the existence and access of `${version}` in `b.xml`.

#### a.xml

---

```
<project name="a" basedir="." >
   ...
   <target name="determine.version">
      ...
   </target>

   ... 

   <import file="b.xml" as="b" />
</project>
```

#### b.xml

```
<project name="b" basedir="." >
   ...
   <target name="example" depends="determine.version">
      ...
      do s.th. with ${version}
      ...
   </target>

</project>
```

I am thankful for any advice, recommendation or comment to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to keep `b.xml` such that it will work when used directly / independently of a.xml, one solution would be to setup b.xml with its own `determine.version` target and override that target in a.xml.

**b.xml** would need:

```
<target name="determine.version">
  ... does nothing or whatever is needed to satisfy b's "example" target when a.xml not used
</target>
```

**a.xml** can then override `determine.version` and depend on the default implementation in b.xml so it is called in the correct position when evaluating b.xml's "example" target. The way to reference a dependency of imports is to specify `{buildfile}.targetname` - in this case `b.determine.version` - assuming that you want both a+b's `determine.version` to run:

```
<target name="determine.version" depends="b.determine.version">
  ...
</target>
```

**Alternatively**

The above setup is awkward in that the names used in a/b xml are linked. Instead you could try out `extension-point` in ant builds which makes names in a depend on b, but not both ways. It would need something like this:

**b.xml** - B declares an extension point that referenced by "example":

```
<extension-point name="setupversion" />
<target name="example" depends="setupversion">
```

**a.xml** - A declares a target (which does not need to be called determine.version) that will run before all targets that depend on "setupversion"

```
<import file="b.xml" />
<target name="determine.version" extensionOf="setupversion">
```

Comment: I ended up implementing an `extension-point`. It appears to be a clean way to add dependencies of unknown external targets. Thank you for outlining this! :)